# String1.equalsIgnoreCase(String2) returns false even though both have same value

Tags: android, string, stream, equals

In my app, I am reading from HTTP page and converting the Stream via the below method into String.

```
public static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is)
{
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A"); 
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

However, once I have the String, I am comparing to another String (manually created in eclipse) which has the exact same component, (which is a copy paste from the same HTML file on my server). The comparison is returning me false.

I am using s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2). Below is an image how my 2 strings are exactly alike.

[image: Identical Strings]

Comment: Try calling .trim() on the strings first.

Comment: @RaghavSood. Success. Calling trim on the String that was made from the Stream fixed the issue. many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, one of your Strings has some whitespace that results in them being unequal upon comparison.

Calling `.trim()` on the Strings before you compare them should fix this.

Comment: Raghav, if you think the question might be helpful for others, why not upvote ?